# how to use the postgres database embedded with Mac Lion?

Tags: database, macos, postgresql

i can only find psql command, but can't find any other postgres commands or tools, can 
anyone tell me how to create database and connect to it using the default postgres 
shipped with mac lion?

only if it doesn't work ,i dont' want to install another postgres instance.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL will be started by Launchd, if configured so.

Look for `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postgresql.postgres.plist`, this is an XML file and you will need to modify some settings there, like `listen_address`.
Default location for the `PGDATA` files is `/var/pgsql`, also found in the `plist` file above.

Cluster is owned by the `_postgres` user, so to access the “tools”, you should execute them via the `sudo -u _postgres …` prefix, like: `sudo -u _postgres pg_ctl -D /var/pgsql -w start`
I highly recommend creating another role with superuser permissions, as _postgres is sharing password with the Administrator account of your Lion.

You can also use the [Server Admin tools for Lion](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1419) to control PostgreSQL and other services:

```sh
sudo serveradmin list
# look for postgres in the output
sudo serveradmin fullstatus postgres

sudo serveradmin stop postgres
sudo serveradmin start postgres
```

Check the version of your PostgreSQL cluster, using: `sudo -u _postgres psql -tc "select version()"` and refer to the official manuals on how to create the database and setup initial access. Manual for the latest PostgreSQL version can be found [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/).

Comment: thanks vyegorov, but there's no such file in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons and psql is in /usr/bin/psql

Comment: by the way ,i didn't install mac lion server

Comment: What `sudo serveradmin list` reports?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the software installed, I strongly recommend the [Enterprise DB](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#osx) package.  It makes installing pretty darn easy.